# New home page question layout is missing the yellow emphasis for watched tags

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

The new question list layout overall seems pretty reasonable, but there used to be yellow highlights for questions from watched tags. This was extremely useful for finding questions I care about without having to explicitly hide *every* technology I'm unfamiliar with.

If I recall correctly, these highlights only appears on SO, due to having such a high volume of questions.

Comment: Already reported on MSE and [meta-tag:status-review]: [New post summary designs on greatest hits now, everywhere else eventually](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375479/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon: Thanks. I'll leave this here for a few hours in case someone else has the same issue.

Comment: Homepage now shows an odd yellow colored box next to every question that says "Watched". Seems pretty awful compared to just coloring the background.

Comment: the high-contrast view adds some very nice orange tags that do stand out

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier I don't want tags that stand out, I want titles that stand out.  That's half as many places I need to look.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I had the exact same reaction. Added these Stylus rules... `.s-post-summary--stats-item.is-watched{display: none;} .s-post-summary.s-post-summary__watched{background-color:var(--black-025);}`